# How to stop a process over a consistent time interval in order to execute a measurement function?

Tags: c, linux, ptrace

I am using the Linux ptrace API in a profiler I am writing.

My pseudo C code looks like this:

```
setjmp();
measure();
alarm(N);
while(1) {
    waitpid(child, &status, WNOHANG);
    if(child_process_exiting) {
        measure();
        break;
    }
}
```

The alarm signal handler is as follows:

```
void sig_handler(int sig) {
     signal(SIGALRM, sig_handler);
     longjmp(env, 0);
 }
```

I want to repeatedly return to the setjmp call until the child process exits and breaks the loop. The goal is to run the measure function every N seconds until the child process exits.

Comment: You do know that you have to call `waitpid` with the `WNOHANG` flag or it will block?

Comment: I did not. Thanks. Edited.

Comment: By the way, using `setjmp`/`longjmp` in combination with signals my not work on all systems. To be safe you should use `sigsetjmp`/`siglongjmp`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I continue to work this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simple just sleep for `N` seconds, then do the `measure` call? If you install a `SIGCHLD` handler to catch when the child process exits, then e.g. [`sleep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sleep.html) will be interrupted and return the number of seconds left.

Something like

```
signal(SIGCHLD, sigchld_handler);

do
{
    measure();
} while (sleep(N) == 0);

waitpid(...);
```

Comment: What action would the handler take in this approach?

Comment: @kobrien Unless the child process can be stopped, the signal handled doesn't have to do anything at all. The `sleep` (and other similar functions) will return anyway when a signal is received.

Answer (score 0):

I only find this need change:

`setjmp(env);` // env is a jum_buf value

Then

```
longjmp(env,1);// so if necessary, we can use :int flag = setjum(env);
```

if flag == 1; I know code call sig_handler and back.